# Rewrite перенос на поддомен

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Подскажите, как сделать перенос такой:

```
сайт.ру/каталог/статья1
```

на

```
статья1.сайт.ру
```

Comment: Попробуйте https://beget.ru/articles/mod_rewrite Третий снизу пример похож на Ваш случай (нужно будет немного модифицировать код)

Comment: Попробовал, но что то не хочет...

Comment: Ну, так напишите код, который работает не так или не работает - хотя бы будет от чего отттолкнуться.